# Magento 1.9 - Change color or email templates

Tags: magento-1.9, email, scss

Im trying to change the color of the standard email templates. I have:

Magento 1.9
Set custom skin to my custom theme
Moved email-inline.scss and email-non-inline1.scss into my custom theme

All I am looking to do is change the background color from grey to white. No matter what i change on both those style sheets, the color does not change. I have even made the changes in the RWD folder, to make sure its not a themeing issue, and the color is still not changing. What i am doing wrong? How can you change the background color of these email templates from grey to white?

thanks !

Comment: Have you confirmed that they are getting compiled to css?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **NOTE:** In my answer I will describe how to do this for Magento's default package and theme. This should work in the same way for the
>   RWD package and `<SCSS>` files. The important part is step 2 and to
>   notice that there are multiple selectors in which the background color
>   is defined.

To change the background color of Magento e-mail templates in Magento CE 1.9.1.0 do the following.

1. Copy the `<CSS>` file

   `skin/frontend/base/default/css/email-inline.css`

   to

   `skin/frontend/YOURPACKAGE/YOURTHEME/css/email-inline.css`
2. Open this file. The default background color for emails used by Magento is `#ebebeb`. This color is defined in several places. You need to find the following selectors

   ```
   body {
       margin: 0;
       padding: 0;
       text-align: left;
       color: #333333;
       background-color: #ebebeb;
   }
   ```

   which is around line 33, and

   ```
   body {
       background: #ebebeb;
       font-size: 12px;
       margin: 0;
       padding: 0;
   }
   ```

   which is around line 55, and

   ```
   html, 
   #background-table {
       background-color: #ebebeb;
   }
   ```

   which is around line 83
3. change the value of the `background` and `background-color` properties to (e.g.) `#fff`.
4. Make sure to flush all cache (just in case...)

This should give you a white background for all Magento email templates.

Comment: perfect! that worked! I was editing the SCSS files instead of the CSS files. Duh.

Comment: my email template showing empty `<style>` tag while I already add `email-inline.css` in every theme folder. Need Help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30504461/magento-1-9-style-email-template