# Change layout transaction email

Tags: layout, email

[image]

I want to change the grey around my white box to white. What do I need to change?

I already tried ->email-inline.scss

```
#background-table {
    background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: You have say to which extend your question differs to existing material we have on site already in the same context. For example, what makes it different to [Magento 1.9 - Change color or email templates](http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/57541/4115)? Next to that you take extremely care on a very specific detail, but most likely your question is not that specific. What is your current experience in editing Magento email templates? Which theme are you using for email-templates?

Comment: Often Yireo has good extensions in the context of magento email templating, they also have a tutorial here that might help: [Customizing Magento email templates](https://www.yireo.com/tutorials/magento/magento-theming/1670-customizing-magento-email-templates) - I haven't read that tutorial, but I've been using the [Email-Tester](https://www.yireo.com/software/magento-extensions/emailtester) and [Email-Override](https://www.yireo.com/software/magento-extensions/email-override) , the later I can suggest to you as I see you're doing translated email templates, is a nice-to-have with that.

Comment: Hello thanks for your comment. I'm using 1.9+ and rwd theme. I followed the steps but it didnt work for me. I think I'm gonna use some extension to solve this problem.

Comment: First of all disable cache. And with RWD theme I think it uses some new stuff with the CSS part of templates. Technically you don't need an extension here. Just to make this chrystal clear.There is even an old-school way to test email-tempaltes, it's just that at work we've got that email-tester plugin and it's quite comfortable.  E.g. see here: [Magento: previewing/testing transactional emails with actual data, without actually sending them?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13823911/367456)

Answer (score 0):

I have only recently discovered the new style emails and so far here's what I found

1) the emails arrive in my inbox with the following code at the top ("defanged" comes from my mail service)

```
<table style="border-collapse:collapse;padding-top:0px;padding-right:0px;padding-bottom:0px;padding-left:0px;margin-top:0px;margin-right:auto;margin-bottom:0px;margin-left:auto;background-color:rgb(235, 235, 235);font-size:14px;" id="defanged16-background-table" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
```

2) in the template header I only have

```
{{var non_inline_styles}}
```

and/or

```
{{inlinecss file="email-inline.css"}}
```

(pattern from the original templates cloned to make my own)

3) the styles in the email are built by [emogrifier](https://github.com/jjriv/emogrifier) using the email css styles in the style build

for example my compiled email-inline.css contains

```
/* line 47, ../../scss/email-inline.scss */
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: left;
  color: #333333;
  background-color: #ebebeb;
}
```

and

```
/* line 68, ../../scss/email-inline.scss */
body {
  background: #ebebeb;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

as well as the background-table entry you found

Changing all three should work

if you are compiling from sass - changing the `$c-email-background` variable should do it

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: left;
    color: $c-gray;
    background-color: $c-email-background;
}


body {
    background: $c-email-background;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}


html,
#background-table {
    background-color: $c-email-background;
}
```

4) the docs I found are unclear whether the system will automatically use your email-inline.css and email-non-inline.css or whether you need to specifically ask for it

for inline [it claims](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/ce19-ee114/RWD_responsive_emails.html#email-css) you need

```
{{inlinecss file="email-inline.css"}}
```

for non inline [it claims](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/ce19-ee114/RWD_responsive_emails.html#email-css) it automatically takes it from 4 sources