# Template Styles not working for magento custom transactional email template

Tags: magento-1.9, transactional-mail

I have created a custom transactional email template and added event in my custom module to send email using this transactional template.

When I add Template Styles in template it is working on preview page but not working in emails.

[image]

Is there any setting in magento to enable this feature or any other method to apply custom css?

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement, check this link to get idea on how to apply custom css in email template:
[Magento 1.9 - Change color or email templates](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/57541/magento-1-9-change-color-or-email-templates)

Comment: I don't want to change all email template layout, wants to change only one email template css.

Comment: You need to create a new class in your template and add style in css. So that new format will only apply in a single template and not in all.

Comment: How to do that, can you please explain?